# How to get a pop-up window for flutter web app?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web, flutter-navigation, flutter-packages

I have been looking for a flutter web app pop-up window but all I could find so far, is a pop-up dart package that just acts like a stack on top on my app, that's not what I want, I want a complete new pop-up window that loads a web page , any help?

Comment: search for flutter showDialog method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I understand:- you want to launch another web page.

`dart:js` enables interoperability between Dart and JS

Sample code :-

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

  FlatButton(
  child: Text('launch another window'),
  onPressed: () {
    js.context.callMethod('open', ['https://google.com/']);
  },
 ),
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way, but you need to deal with web-only libraries lint. Also, this way you get a handle to control the window.

```
import 'dart:html' as html;

html.WindowBase _popup = html.window.open(url, name,'left=100,top=100,width=800,height=600');
if (_popup.closed!) {
  throw("Popups blocked");
}
```